# Coverting Assembler (8086) Command Into Machine Code

Tags: assembly, x86-16, machine-code

I need to translate the Assembler command **`MOV BL,[ALPHA]` into machine code** of intels 8086 processor. Therefore, ALPHA is an 1 Byte variable at the 11th Position of the Data Segment, which is already loaded in the `DS` Register.

I already translated `MOV AL,[ALPHA]` in another task I've got. Here I found the `MOV AL/AX,addr` in the instruction set table so I could translate the whole thing into `1010|0000 1010|0000` or `A0 10` in machine code.

I tend to use `MOV r/m1,r/m2` of the instruction set table, but I am not  100% sure because I got problems when selecting the `r/m` part. Since this is the preparation for an exam I would be really happy if someone could help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That must be a strange instruction set table because there is no `mov r/m1,r/m2` (you can't have two memory references). Better try the [official intel one](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf). What you need is `mov r8, r/m8`. The encoding for that is `8A /r`. Using *Table 2-1. 16-Bit Addressing Forms with the ModR/M Byte* you can see that operand `BL` with a 16 bit displacement `disp16` means a modrm byte of `1E` followed by 16 bit displacement, so the complete instruction is `8A 1E 0A 00`. You can verify that with an assembler:

```
8A1E0A00                mov bl, [10]
```

PS: It's unclear what offset you really want, but I trust you can fill in the correct one.

Comment: Thanks for your time you invest. I think I understand know. In our table we have this one rule and set the bit in which direction we go manually (by setting the 7th bit of that thing 0 or 1 [as far as I understood]), in case of two adresses we must see the problem by ourself. But I could follow your answer with my script :)
A short edit for your answer for other users seeing this: the 11th position translates to `0A 00` and we got no displacement in this task so I think we are fine with this
Many thanks & have a nice weekend (:

Comment: The displacement is the `0A 00` ;)

Comment: Okay, `0A 00` is the displacement. But for which adress is this the disp.? For the next instruction? For data? I think I understood how physical adresses where made in the 8086, but where (code/data/somewhat else) enables that offset? Is an answer possible without further information or does the BL register is used by a specific other register?

Comment: It's your address, which in this case is just a displacement (offset) because you don't have a register in the destination address. The valid forms include `[displacement]`, `[bx+displacement]`, `[bp+si+displacement]` and such.

Comment: Ah yeah, so I'm going to have the data from 0x00A00h in my BL register?!

Comment: Data from `0x000A` (+`ds` segment base), since x86 is little endian. And that address is your `ALPHA`.